# PySnmp - Retrieve just a single mib tree with the bulk command?

Tags: python, pysnmp

I was using the following code.

```
iterator = bulkCmd(
            SnmpEngine(),
            credentials,
            UdpTransportTarget((target_ip, 161), timeout=10, retries=1),
            ContextData(),
            0, 2,
            ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
            lexicographicMode=False
        )
```

In the process of troubleshooting why snmpv3 randomly times out when getting polled using the above code, i was noticing that using the values (0, 100) for example, When trying to poll a simple mib for say ifAlias, i would get all the ifAlias, But also parts of the next mib. For whatever reason it seems to cause the python script to get too many timeouts. Debugging in wireshark i was seeing it (The cisco switch) was replying with more than what i was asking for leading me to believe it's taking a bit too long to reply with what i was looking for.
Is there a way to get PySNMP to just pull the mib itself and anything under that tree? I feel like i'm missing something stupid in the documentation.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: `bulkCmd` only sends a GET BULK message as you wished. If you specify 100 objects to query at most, then it goes and grab as many as the agent allows. Whether you need all the objects is up-to-you. People just don't use a large number here, as SNMP packet size is also limited and agents dislike large responses. This applies to all SNMP implementations, not just PySNMP so won't cover in its docs.